# Route between different subnets in different VLan

Tags: networking, router, routing, switch, vlan

I have a layer 3 switch that has two vlans on it 5 and 10. On each vlan there is an router:

1st router
5 vlan:
192.168.200.254/24

2nd router
10 vlan:
192.168.100.254/24

How do I route between those IP so i could reach each other?

Comment: Are you saying you *defined two IP addresses* for a router (one on each VLAN), but you haven't actually *set up anything to act as actual router* on those IP addresses? So now you're asking us how to set up a router to use those IP addresses you've already allocated? Or are you saying you actually have a router on those addresses, but it's not doing its job? If you're asking why your router isn't routing, you'll need to give us technical details of your router and how exactly you've tried to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand the question but i believe you want to provide Inter-VLAN routing from your Layer 3 switch. This is most commonly done using Switch VLAN Interfaces (SVI).
Example
Layer3-Switch(config)# interface vlan 20
Layer3-Switch(config-if)# ip address x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
Layer3-Switch(config-if)# no shutdown

Providing each VLAN with a VLAN interface, will provide Inter-VLAN Routing. Assuming IP routing is enabled on the switch through the use of the *ip routing* command.